# Is the distinction between language and metalanguage strictly parallel the distinction between logic and metalogic?

Tags: logic, metalogic

The distinction language/metalanguage is often used to explain the difference between logic and metalogic. My question is to know whether this explanation is sufficient. More precisely: : is it true that being formulated in metalanguage is a sufficient condition for a statement to belong to metalogic? ( Assuming the statement is correct).

The reason that leads me to doubt can be expressed by the following reasoning (which surely  goes wrong somewhere) :

(1) Expressions as " being a valid formula", " being a logical consequence of," being derivable from" belong to metalanguage . ( There is no symbol in the object-language to express such properties or relations).

(2) Logicians constantly use these expressions, even at the elementary level. They don't seem interested in using their formal language/ formal system, but in saying things ABOUT  them. In textbooks, exercices ask me to show that a given formula is a tautology, or that a given reasoning is valid, etc.

(3) So , if "belonging to metalanguage" is a sufficient condition to " belonging to metalogic", the discipline called " logic" is in fact " metalogic".

(4) But, if (3) is right, what would a "logic" book look like, in case there were absolutely no metalogic in it?

Origin of the question. Following the advice of a renowned logician in his online guide entitled Teach Yourself Logic, I once bought Jeffrey Hunter's Metalogic. The book crossed the ocean, arrived in France, and I began to study it. I have not been  disappointed and found Hunter's book illuminating. However, after some reflection ( some will say : "... not deep enough reflection") I said to myself: " but if this is META-logic, could there be any room left for logic?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it true that being formulated in metalanguage is a sufficient condition for a statement to belong to metalogic?

Not exactly. Consider the following example : an English book about Greek grammar is about a language : Greek, and it is written in English, the metalanguage. But it is not logic nor about logic.

But, yes,

> the distinction between language and metalanguage strictly parallel the distinction between logic and metalogic.

See S.C.Kleene, [Introduction to metamathematics (1952)](https://books.google.it/books?id=O28-AQAAIAAJ&dq=editions%3Ag72qKY6e9igC), page 62 :

> To Hilbert is due the emphasis that strict formalization of a theory involves the total abstraction from the meaning, the result being called a *formal system* (or sometimes a *formal theory*); and second, his method of making the formal system as a whole the object of a mathematical study called *metamathematics* or proof theory.
>
> In dealing with a particular formal system, we may call the system the *object theory*, and the metamathematics relating to it its *metatheory*.

We have that *metamathematics* is the mathematical discipline that studies the properties of those specific mathematical objects that are the *formalized theories*.

When the formalized theory is a logical calculus, like e.g. *propositional calculus* or *predicate calculus*, the metamathematical discipline studying them can be quite obviously called : *metalogic*.

This is consistent with what G.Hunter asserts in the [*Preface* (p.xi)](https://books.google.it/books?id=oHpMtskGcv0C&pg=PR11) :

> The main contents are : Proof of the consistency, completeness and decidability of a formal system of standard truth-functional propositional logic. The same for first-order monadic predicate logic.

---

Considering specific examples, we have that :

(1) $p \to q$ is a formula of propositional calculus, i.e. an expression of the *object language*, written using the symbols of the language, like $\to$.

$\vDash (p \to p)$ is a statement in the *metalanguage*, asserting that formula $(p \to p)$ is *valid*.

The symbol $\vDash$ is not part of the calculus, i.e. is not part of the *object language*. It is a metalinguistic expression.

Regarding (2): exactly; a mathematical logic textbook is "made of" very few parts written in the object language : basically, only the initial examples of formulas and derivations, aimed at showing "how the calculus works".

The main part of the book is "metalogic" : it is metalogical the description of the syntax of the formal system. It is metalogical the proof of theorems like the *Deduction Theorem* and the *Soundness* and *Completeness Theorems*, i.e. the mathematical theorems expressing the properties of the formal system.

In conclusion, regarding (3): yes, a mathematical logic book is a *metalogic* book.

Compare with a textbook named "Physics": it is a book stating the *physical theory*, i.e. the theory regarding the facts of the physical realm.

Comment: Maybe you could change the example: and instead of English book say Spanish book. 
"Consider the following example : an Spanish book about Greek grammar is about a language : Greek, and it is written in Spanish, the metalanguage. But it is not logic nor about logic. "
Not sure if you are talking about your sentence or the meaning of your sentence...