# I am looking for an easy explaination about Metalanguage in mathematics

Tags: logic, soft-question

We define that statements are objects that *fullfill* a certain syntax. But this *definition* itself is a statement. It is a variant of saying: If the object *fulfils* a certain syntax then it is a statement because it also fulfils a certain syntax. This is again a statement about the statement and so on...

I know this is very informal and I have started to read a book about logic but the author said he will talk about this subject first at chapter 7 and I hoped that I maybe could get an informal but still comprehensible "peek" of the problem: That we are defining an object in a *lower* language that still is *applicable* to *higher* languages. To me it seems like proving something for fields and then saying that it also holds for rings.

Comment: Have you seen this?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox

Comment: What would be the conclusion of the paradox?

Comment: He created a new structure for logical objects called "types" so this way it would be possible to separate what is a set and its elements when you have paradoxes like that.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory

Comment: The paradox "there is a set that contains all sets" is about sets but it is analgous to the paradox that "there is a language that describes all languages"?

Comment: Language could be a set, just define it in a formal way. For instance, language A is the set of symbols such that the proposition p is true.
You are talking about if a language that describes all languages should describe itself or not, right? Then, it seems that the analogy holds.

Comment: You have not actually asked a question.

Comment: Regardeless, the problem is likely in your second sentence. A definition is *not* a statement. Certainly when we formalize logic, "statement" usually means (well-formed, and possibly also closed) formula, and a definition is not a formula in this sense. But even without formalization, the sentence "Define $x$ to be $3$." is not a declarative statement but an imperative one. It doesn't make sense to ask whether "Define $x$ to be $3$" is true any more than it makes sense to ask whether "Sit!" is true. A definition is a command to the reader, not an assertion.

Comment: See e.g [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3159383/is-the-distinction-between-language-and-metalanguage-strictly-parallel-the-disti) and many others on this site about "meta-".

Answer (score 2):

See [An Elementary Latin Grammar](https://books.google.it/books?id=3XIXAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA85) :

> The statement "Cesar scribit" [means] *Caesar is writing*.

We have here the Latin language, which is the *object* of the study; call it : *object* language.

And we have the English language, used to perform the study; call it : *meta*-language.

The statement "Cesar scribit" is a statement in the object language.

The statement "The statement "Cesar scribit" [means] *Caesar is writing*." is a statement of the meta-language that expresses a fact about the object language statement "Cesar scribit".

And now compare with : D.van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](https://www.cin.ufpe.br/~mlogica/livros/Logic%20and%20Structure%20-%20Van%20Dalen.pdf), page 7 :

> **Definition 1.1.2** The set $\text {PROP}$ of propositions is the smallest set $X$ with
>   the properties
>
> > (i) $p_i ∈ X(i ∈ \mathbb N), \bot ∈ X$,
> >
> > (ii) $ϕ, ψ ∈ X ⇒ (ϕ ∧ ψ), (ϕ ∨ ψ), (ϕ → ψ), (ϕ ↔ ψ) ∈ X$,
> >
> > (iii) $ϕ ∈ X ⇒ (¬ϕ) ∈ X$.

It is a statement in the meta-language : the usual mathematical [*argot*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cant_(language)#Argot), made of natural language plus symbols used as abbreviations, regarding the syntax of the object language : the language of *propositional calculus*.

> "this definition itself is a statement" ?

Yes; it is a statement in the meta-language defining the formal syntax of the objcet language.